# How to change rmarkdown/bookdown word_document citation and bibliography style

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, bookdown

For an article I am writing I need to adhere to a specific bibliography/citation style (the SAGE Harvard reference style).

I have the correct bibliography file (in this case `SageH.bst`) and would like to set this as a style for the word_document output.

I know that this is possible for pdf documents using the `biblio-style` parameter. However, this does not seem to work for Word documents and I find no reference in the Rmarkdown or bookdown manuals on how and if it is even possible to specify the style.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `.bst` file supplied by the publisher, I was able to set the bibliography style using `pandoc_args` and a csl file from the [Zotero Style Repository](https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=sage).

For anyone wondering, the correct (simplified) options supplied to the `_output.yml` should have been:

```
bookdown::word_document2:
 reference_docx: "template.docx"
 pandoc_args: [
   --csl=sage-harvard.csl
 ]
```